# linux centos root crontab will not run

Tags: linux, cron

I added the following using "crontab -e":

```
* 6 * * *  rsync -arthv /content/ 192.168.1.1:/content  > /tmp/db_rsync.log 2>&1
```

when I do `crontab -l` I see the line.

am I missing something?
It's not running. It does run manually.

Answer (score 1):

The PATH for cron is unlikely to be the same as the one you use interactively. Try changing `rsync` to `/usr/bin/rsync`.

Answer (score 1):

or you can specify the  path in crontab as

```
PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin

* 6 * * *  rsync -arthv /content/ 192.168.1.1:/content  > /tmp/db_rsync.log 2>&1
```